# Value of optional type not unwrapped

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var simpleText: UITextField! 
  @IBOutlet weak var simpleLable: UILabel!

  @IBAction func changeText(sender: AnyObject) {
    simpleLable.text + ()
    simpleLable.text = "Hello, " + simpleText.text
  }
}
```

Getting Error in `changeText` function and the error is

> Value of the optional type String ? not unwrapped

not mean to use ! or ??

What do I do ?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to get with this method?

What `simpleLable.text + ()` should do?

It seems that you want to get entered by user text in label. You should unwrap `simpleText.text` because it is optional. You can unwrap your `text` with `??`.

```
@IBAction func changeText(sender: AnyObject) {
  simpleLable.text = "Hello, " + simpleText.text ?? ""
}
```

It means: if `simpleText.text == nil` (e.g. does not exist) put empty string instead.